# Controlling ordering of Django queryset result via filtering with redis list

Tags: django, redis, django-views, django-queryset

On a Django website of mine, users contribute posts, which are then showed globally on the home page, sorted by most-recent first.

I'm introducing redis into this mix, via doing an `lpush` of all post_ids into a redis list (which is kept trimmed at 1000 entries). The code is:

```
def add_post(link_id):
    my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
    my_server.lpush("posts:1000", link_id)
    my_server.ltrim("posts:1000", 0, 9999)
```

Then, when a user requests the contents of the home page, I simply execute the following query in the `get_queryset` method of the relevant class-based view:

`Post.objects.filter(id__in=all_posts())`

Where `all_posts()` is simply:

```
def all_posts():
    my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
    return my_server.lrange("posts:1000", 0, -1)
```

Next, I iterate over the `context["object_list"]` in a Django template (i.e. `{% for post in object_list %`}, and one by one populate the latest posts for my users to see.

**My problem is that this arrangement does not show most-recent first.** It always shows most-recent last. So I changed `lpush` to `rpush` instead, *but the result didn't change at all.* Why isn't changing redis' list insert method changing the ordering of the results Django's queryset is returning to me?

Perhaps I'm missing something rudimentary. Please advise me on what's going on, and how can I fix this (is `{% for post in object_list reversed %}` my sole option here). My reason for taking the redis route was, naturally, performance. Prior to redis, I would do: `Post.objects.order_by('-id')[:1000]` Thanks in advance.

*Note: please ask for more information if required*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating through a queryset that doesn't have an `order_by` clause, which means that you can't have any expectations about the order or the results. The `__in` clause just controls *which* rows to return, not their order.

The fact that the returned results are in the `id` order is an implementation detail. If you want to rely on that, you can just iterate through the queryset in reverse order. A more robust solution would be to reorder (in Python) the instances based on the order of the ids returned from Redis.

All that said, though, I don't think there will be any performance advantage to using Redis here. I think that any relational database with an index on `id` will be able to execute `Post.objects.order_by('-id')[:1000]` very efficiently. (Note that slicing a queryset does a `LIMIT` on the database; you're not fetching all the rows into Python and then slicing a huge list.)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful - cleared my concepts. BTW, redis did help indeed. It took my server response time from ~95ms to ~4ms for this particular query. I guess it varies from case-to-case, but in mine it did wonders! Thanks again.